# Installed pow.cx, http://appname.dev could not be opened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I installed http://pow.cx on OS X 10.6.7 and I have rvm.
I installed the powder gem https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder

I ran "powder" in my app directory
The symlink is definitely there, I checked.

When I go to http:// appname.dev (obviously appname is replaced with the app name, also I can't post more than two links for ten days, so the space is because of that), neither Chrome nor Safari can open it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried searching here and google.

I went to http:// localhost/ and I got a "No such app" message from pow

appname/ didn't work...

I have config.ru in my root...

/!\ FIXED /!\ ## NARKOZ was right. Reboot did it.

Comment: I had this issue too. Restart helped me.

Comment: Yep! Welp... the docs didn't have a troubleshooting tip, and I didn't expect a reboot requirement ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot!

https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/108#issuecomment-1068124

Answer (score 3):

The actual fault here is Chrome's "Built-in Asynchronous DNS", disable this in chrome://flags and it'll work again.

Comment: disable 'Built-in Asynchronous DNS' fix my problem.